# How do I sort a Ruby array of strings by length?

Tags: ruby, sorting, arrays

How do I sort this:

```
arr = ["aaa","aa","aaaa","a","aaaaa"];
```

Into this?

```
arr = ["a","aa","aaa","aaaa","aaaaa"];
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
arr = arr.sort_by {|x| x.length}
```

Or in 1.8.7+:

```
arr = arr.sort_by(&:length)
```

Comment: Sorry for commenting on such an old post, but could you explain what &:length is and why it works? Is it calling the method length? What is the significance of & ?

Comment: @DanR Yes, it's calling the method `length` on every item yielded by `sort_by` - exactly like the first line. The prefix `&` operator converts an object (specifically a Proc object or any object that has a `to_proc` method, which symbol objects do) to a block. In case of symbols that will be a block that calls the method with the given name on its argument (as that's how `Symbol#to_proc` is defined).

Answer (score 12):

You can also use [`sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sort):

```
arr.sort{|x, y| x.length <=> y.length}
```

Answer (score 5):

`arr = arr.sort{|x,y| x.length - y.length}` works too.